# WiFi slow in Ubuntu 20.10, but not in Windows 10

Tags: wireless, 20.04, 20.10

Good day!

I recently switched to Ubuntu 20.04. I noticed that WiFi speeds weren't as fast as in Windows 10. The upgrade to 20.10 didn't help either.

I'm not really well versed in Linux, but I tried a few things like disabling/enabling 802.11n, disabling IPv6 and reinstalling the drivers, none of which changed anything.

The WiFi card is a cheap Chinese USB dongle and uses the mt76x2u driver.
When I run iwconfig, the bit rate fluctuates and is 54 Mbps at its maximum, resulting in WiFi speeds of around 25 Mbps when transfering files to and from my server, which is in the same network.

On Windows 10 I easily achieve ~140 Mbps.
I have uploaded the output of the 'wireless-info' script mentioned in another WiFi related post: https://pastebin.com/fLmeg90L

I hope someone can help me, as this is the only thing that's really keeping me from fully committing to Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: In your paste, we see: "disabling HT/VHT/HE as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP" HT=high throughput; VHT=very high throughput; that is, speed! Is WMM and/or QoS an available setting in your router? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! QoS is available on my router. But how does that relate to my WiFi speeds? Under Windows everything works just fine.

Comment: Okay! I've enabled WMM and QoS and I'm getting higher speeds now!
I can't thank you enough!
How come I didn't find this answer anywhere else? And can you still explain to me why it works under Windows without those settings, but not under Linux?

Comment: I shall propose an answer that you may accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your paste, we see: "disabling HT/VHT/HE as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP" HT refers to high throughput and VHT to very high throughput; that is, speed! AP refers to the access point, in home networking, usually a wireless router.

Is WMM and/or QoS an available setting in your router?

Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions

A great many things work perfectly in Windows and less than perfectly or, indeed, not at all in Linux and vice versa. I believe that the wireless driver is completely different in each operating system.

Linux will, indeed, always have driver issues, but for several reasons that may not be apparent to all of us. First, new devices are developed and released every day. The manufacturers are in a constant arms race to have a better device with more features and, often, cheaper. In almost every case, they have no concern for the 3% or so of Linux users and therefor don't provide a perfectly working driver.

Second, most new Linux users come to the party with what they have now that they bought with working Windows drivers. That device may work well or not at all in Linux. Experienced Linux users always check the forums and are sure the device works in Linux.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions! I've actually been using Linux for about three years now, but still consider myself a beginner (because of the unimaginable learning curve). I will heed your advice in the future!